# Why doesn't 'tail x : head x' work?

Tags: haskell

New to Haskell. Why does the following code **not** work? How do I concatenate the tail and the head like this?

```
func :: [String] -> [String]
func x = tail x:head x
```

Comment: `:` doesn't mean "concatenate". It specifically takes a single element (on the left) and a list (on the right) and produces a new list.

Comment: @melpomene I see. So how do you suggest I properly concatenate this?

Comment: I'd suggest something like `func (x : xs) = xs ++ [x]`. Note that `++` is linear in the length of its left argument so you probably don't want to do this in a loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets work through the types to understand why this didn't work before we focus on the proper solution.

You presented:

```
func :: [String] -> [String]
func x = tail x:head x
```

We know:

```
tail x :: [String]
head x :: String
(:)    :: String -> [String] -> [String]
            ^          ^ the 'head' argument's position
            ^---the 'tail' argument's position
```

So clearly the types aren't matching up - a list where an element is expected and an element where a list is expected.

It's worth noting that there isn't any default `snoc` operator, which cons's an element to the end of a list.  What you can do is append to lists via `(++) :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]`. Since the `head xs` isn't a `[String]` we could make it one via square brackets: `[head xs]`.

More-over, the use of `head` and `tail` are not safe - they'll throw an exception if the list is empty.  It is better to use pattern matching so the compiler can warn you about partial functions in addition to them being more visibly obvious.  In this case we'd match the first element and the rest of the list:

```
func (firstElement : restOfList) = restOfList ++ [firstElement]
```

And looking at this it should be obvious `func` isn't yet defined for empty lists so we can add one more case:

```
func [] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Change

```
func :: [String] -> [String]
func x = tail x:head x
```

to

```
func :: [String] -> [String]
func x = tail x++[head x]
```

Comment: This won't work because `tail x:[head x]` is still a type error.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Edited.

Comment: You probably also want an empty list case, as there seems to be no need for this function to fail on an empty list.

Comment: `tail` and `head`, being partial, should be avoided in most common cases, preferring pattern matching to them.